# What the relationship between HttpApplication and HttpContext class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

The [HttpApplication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication(v=vs.110).aspx) have a property [Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.context(v=vs.110).aspx) which class is [HttpContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx).

**HttpContext** class and **HttpApplication** class have some common property, such as *User*, *Response*, *Request*.
What's the difference and relationship between these property in two class.
In what situation should I use the the one other than the other.

PS: I have just check my application, *HttpApplication.User* and *HttpApplication.Context.User* have the same value.

Answer (score 4):

Your comparison seems to be wrong.

Because the [HttpContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) only handles the things related to the HTTP protocol specific information for the current request.

But the  [HttpApplication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication(v=vs.110).aspx) holds the whole ASP.NET Application objects such as Events,  methods, properties, etc., Yes. It has the  Context property, which is a type of `System.Web.HttpContext`. It is used to encapsulates the HTTP-specific information for each and every request that made against the particular ASP.NET Application.

Comment: why HttpApplication.User and HttpApplication.Context.User have the same value? When should I use HttpApplication.User instead of HttpApplication.Context.User

Answer (score 3):

HttpContext.User is read-write.  HttpApplication.User is read-only.  That is the only difference.

If you disassemble System.Web you'll find this bit of code for HttpApplication.User:

```
public IPrincipal User
{
    get
    {
        if (this._context == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(SR.GetString("User_not_available"));
        }
        return this._context.User;
    }
}
```

So aside from a null check, the two properties do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should learn what is ASP.NET pipeline and page lifecycle, then the usage of the two classes would become obvious.

`HttpApplication` is the pipeline implementation which loads the HTTP modules and handlers. Incoming requests are processed by its instances.

`HttpContext` is just the context object, which holds the request and response messages. It is a convenient way to capture all request related data so that by passing such an object inside `HttpApplication`, the modules/handlers can easily know what happens and when they should jump in.

About why they have similar properties, you can refer to the .NET Framework reference source published by Microsoft. In most cases, they should be duplicate to each other, and exist just for convenience.